# How to replace a String which is having escapes in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I am unable to replace the string \"@salePriceAdjId@\" which is in a file in groovy. I have googled it but found no luck.

```
String str = new File("C:\\example.txt").getText();

Str.replaceAll("\\"+'"'@salePriceAdjId@\\"+'"',1234567890)
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? What does not work? Do you want to replace the text in the file or just in the variable?

Comment: Please add the error you get or the unexpected behaviour you see as well to the question.  "Does not work" leaves a lot of room for interpreation.

Comment: @TomStroemer first I am reading file into a string and then replacing the string and then after replacing the value in a string I am just writing the string into the same file but while replacing the string its not getting replaced

Comment: What's the question? Should we guess the file content?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Groovy's regexp literals for this. Also `replaceAll()` doesn't mutate the `str`, you have to reassign:

```
String str = 'a vvvvvvvvvvvv \"@salePriceAdjId@\" aaaaa' // new File("C:\\example.txt").text

String val = '\\"@salePriceAdjId@\\"' // get from somewhere

str = str.replaceAll( /$val/, '1234567890')

assert str == 'a vvvvvvvvvvvv 1234567890 aaaaa'
```

Comment: @injecter my value is dynamic so that it is coming from different file and my string value is str = "@salePriceAdjId@" then how to add the str.replaceAll( /str/, '1234567890'). I mean if I have placed a variable then how to concatenate it